# Firebase on IOS 10 not loading data from Database on real device

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, ios10

Currently working on a Firebase app on IOS 10 have been using Firebase UI. When I run the app on my simulator, it works fine and the data from FirebaseUI and a simple Firebase Database call grabbing the same data works (testing reasons to ensure it's not FirebaseUI).

BUT... when I switch to testing on a real device. My Tableview is empty, and the logs show no data is being pulled, not even a confirmation of user authorization that I log out.

I've tried changing the "bitcode" to no as suggested by another post, but still nothing. I am using Objective C, and not swift. Any thoughts?

Comment: your simulator and device are connected to the same network?

Comment: Yes, I am on a school network. My simulator is hard wired and my real device is connected to their wifi.

Comment: then does it work when the simulator is on wifi? (shooting in the dark here)

Comment: I'm actually using a MacPro without a Wifi card so I can't even be certain of that. I've tried to use my real device on a different Wifi and had no luck.

Comment: I am having the same problem now. It happened after messing with certificates for messaging. Have you solved this?

Comment: I realized something was happening with my user object that my data was dependent on in the firebase rules tabs. I logged out and logged back in to confirm the Auth went through and it worked again for me.

Comment: I hope this helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/41200174/2294985

Comment: Here what helped me: I explicitly logged out from real device and then sign in again, and DB immediately start responding. I think Firebase cached key and didn't renew it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the pod 'Firebase/Core' in your Podfile, and "import FirebaseCore" in your Swift file.

Comment: How it can be the correct answer?  If pod isn't installed or some import missing, you won`t be able to even compile the app.

Comment: It was something like 'import Firebase' before, there is a name change.

Comment: same situation for worked for me in Database, even I installed Firebase and Fireabase/Database, for not installing Firebase/Core, database did not respond to any action